# GitHub - Code quality and failing builds due to merge

Tags: github, build, merge

Consider the following scenario;

- A pull request is submitted from a forked repository branch - in GitHub
- The submitted PR passes all checks - Circle CI, code coverage etc.
- The maintainers merged the PR after some time to the original master. However 
  the build breaks on master **due to the merge**.
- In such cases Insights >> Contributors >> commits (under contributor name) shows that one of the commits of this contributor have failed.

Are such scenarios common?

In such a situation, who is usually supposed to take the responsibility of the build break?

Can this be used to measure/ judge the quality of code delivered by this contributor?

Comment: *Can this be used to measure/ judge the quality of code delivered by this contributor?* no. It only shows that the maintainer, who merged, hasn't made sure to test the result of the merge before merging. If you really want to blame someone (which is useless), then you should blame the maintainer. A better way to work, IMHO, would be to rebase the PR on master, test, and then push to master (thus doing a fast forward).

Comment: Do you require the branch to be updated to the latest default branch before merging?